# Suspicious links showing on cPanel --> visitors

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel, spam, brute-force

I am facing a problem with my wordpress site. Number of visitors try to access a page that doesn't even exist on my site. It keeps generating every minute with different random php links from different ip. I installed wordfence but those pages are not showing on wordfence traffic. By facing this my site bandwidth increasing hugely.

Please refer this screenshot.
[image]

I also facing number of ip try to access my wp-login page and xmlrpc page as well.

I don't know where this came from and how to solve.

Comment: Your site is being probed, just like every other site on the web. You could install fail2ban that will block some of this traffic, or you can get a Cloudflare service or similar that can block this traffic.

Comment: Thank you for you reply.. But it probing the pages are not even exist on my website.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming. [Webmasters.se] might be abetter place to ask, but check their help before posting.